# Gradients for polygons in OpenGL

Tags: c++, c, opengl

what is the best way to create a gradient for a 2D polygon in OpenGL, (Linear, and Radial)?

Thanks

How can you generate textures for radial gradients on the fly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear is very easy - you just set different colors to different points like

```
red ---- red
|        |
|        |
|        |
blue ---- blue
```

for radial texture might be better option

to generate it on fly create empty texture then fill it with function sqrt((MAXX - x)^2 + (MAXY - y)^2), then add color to it.

Comment: You could use the first method with several triangles to simulate a radial gradient.

Comment: ... and I would use the triangle fan primitive to ease the geometry construction for radial gradient.

Comment: @Luca i thought about it, but i think it will not look nice. texture will be certanly better

Comment: You may wish to generate the triangle fan using the sin and cosine functions - create a quick routine for it and it will grant you greater flexibility than a texture will, methinks.